# Process items one by one when use websocket and BackgroundWorker C#

Tags: c#

I have WPF program which listens what income data from Pushbullet through websocket (onMessage event)

The process of data is done in a background worker (in DoWork event) in order to not freeze the UI.

But might happen the data are more than one and seems that results are broken.

```
WS.onMessage += (s, ev) => { 
    var wk = new BackgroundWorker();
    wk.DoWork += (se, evt) => {
        Process1();
        Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{ print to ui });
    } 

     wk.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

How to process item one by one when onMessage is triggered? I mean I want to process an item and the process another after first is done even onMessage is already triggered few times, depends how many data comes ...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive"). Then you can do this:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<EventHandler, EventArgs>(
            h => WS.onMessage += h, h => WS.onMessage -= h)
        .SelectMany(ep => Observable.Start(() => Process1()))
        .ObserveOnDispatcher()
        .Subscribe(x =>
        {
            /* Print to UI */
        });
```

It'll process on a background thread and then marshall back to the dispatcher. It'll produce zero or more values in the `.Subscribe` method and will only produce one value at a time.

If you want to close down the observable just call `.Dispose()` on the subscription.

You might need to adjust the `EventHandler` & `EventArgs` types to suit your source event.

Comment: Seems complicated, I thought using `lock` statement somewhere